# Error running Google App Engine Standard via IntelliJ - can't find appengine-web.xml

Tags: kotlin, google-app-engine, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to locally run/debug a Google App Engine Standard app written in Kotlin.  Here's the basic stack:

- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate
- Google App Engine Standard
- Gradle
- Kotlin

I followed these directions: https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/deploy-local#running_your_application_locally
So far so good.

But when I go to run it (via IntelliJ Run menu), I get the following error:

> NoSuchFileException during local run: Error occurred during local run. Please first confirm that there is a properly placed appengine-web.xml file. If missing, either use the Cloud Code shortcut action under: 'Tools > Cloud Code > Add App Engine Support > Google App Engine Standard' Or manually generate an appengine-web.xml file in the WEB-INF directory of your module's web resource directory, (show balloon)

> Error running '(my run config)': Encountered an error starting the App Engine local development server process.

AFAIK, the file is in the correct place (I even tried deleting it and having Google's plugin regenerate it for me - it put it in the same place/same name).

[image: project file structure]

**Any ideas how to fix this error?**  I've spent 2 days just debugging various tool issues with this stack, but can't get past this one.

UPDATE:
Here's the run configuration I'm using.
[image: run config]

Comment: What Run/Debug configuration type do you use? Does it work via Gradle?

Comment: @CrazyCoder: Yep, it runs via Gradle/Terminal.  I updated the question with a screenshot of the run config.

Comment: If you check the artifact output directory, do you see appengine-web.xml file there?

Comment: @CrazyCoder: Yeah, it shows up in the build/exploded-(project name)/WEB-INF folder and in the libs/(project name).war if I look at the contents of that.

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA and attach a sample project to reproduce. Specify the GAE version you are using.

Comment: I am running into this exact scenario.  Any resolution?

Comment: @that_developer: unfortunately, I don't think we ever resolved this.  We switched to a Spring Boot setup shortly after and haven't really looked back.  If you end up finding a resolution though, I'd still be interested in it (as I'm sure anyone else finding this thread would be too).

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on the project, then click on `Open Module Settings`.

Under `Project Settings` click on `Artifacts`.

Choose your `war exploded` file.

You should notice that on the `Output Layout` tab under `Available Elements` you will need to add your JPA descriptors by double-clicking that.
This resolved the issue for me with on this exact error.
[image]

Comment: Interesting!  We're not using JPA in our stuff AFAIK, but glad you figured it out for your project.  Hopefully that helps someone else here.